# how to call method from java file in javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, methods

I am new in JavaScript.  I want to know how to call a simple method in Java file from JavaScript program.  Could you please give me a simple example as well?

Thank you

Comment: Please find your shift key & use it (once at the start of every sentence, and for every use of the word 'I' at the very least).  This is a technical forum, not a social networking site.

Comment: By Java file you mean an Applet or Application or server side code (Servlet)?

Comment: I think you need to explain what do you mean by _"Java file"_. Is it a Java file lying on your machine, an Applet or a server side method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript will not be able to access server side java code directly.
It will need to make an ajax call to access a method or make a http call.

If you have applets you will be able to access the applet java code.

See example here
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/js_java.html

Comment: thank you.  i thought i can call java method directly.  i'll try to use applet.

Answer (score 3):

When you say "java file" I presume you mean a Java applet.  In that case, say you have this applet code on your page:

```
<applet id="myapplet" class="MyApplet.class" ... />
```

If you wanted to call the helloWorld() method in that applet, you simply need to do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    document.getElementById['myapplet'].helloWorld();
</script>
```